# Tengo dos numeros y uno debe es mayor hasta cierto rango

Tags: javascript, jquery

espero se encuentren bien.

Tengo este problema, sucede que tengo un if el cual muestra una alerta la cual valida datos que traigo desde un formulario, es decir traigo dos datos, el los compara y dice si **Upslotsmas es <= a Upslots** muestreme la alerta, en caso de ser mayor siga a la siguiente accion.

Hasta ahi todo bien, el problema es que los datos me lo toma como si fuera STRING, es decir.

```
var upslotsmas = "30"
var upslots = "50"

$(upslotsmas).val() <= $(upslots).val()) {
alert 'ES MENOR'
}
```

Cuando registro en upslotsmas el numero 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, bien, pero al momento de poner un 6 el cual es menor a 50 el me lo toma como mayor, me imagino que por que el toma 1 10 11 12 13 .......2 20 21 22 23 .... 3 30 31 32 33.

Gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: has probado usar la función de javascript parseInt(numeroString) para convertir tus "numeros string" a enteros??

Comment: Hola David, soy nuevo en el tema, tu me podrias explicar como podria hacerlo?

Comment: `if(Number($(upslotsmas).val()) <= Number($(upslots).val())) { alert("Es menor") }`

Comment: parseInt($(upslotsmas).val()) de esta forma obtienes el valor y lo pasa a entero, debes hacerlo con los dos valores.

Comment: Es preferible usar `Number` en vez de `parseInt`. `parseInt("45a")` retorna el numero `45`, aún cuando `45a` no es un numero válido. `Number` si devuelve error con `45a`

Comment: Muchas gracias a ambos, lo solucioné con el Number, ya que el parseInt me traia tambien el Id que estaba registrando. Muchas Gracias.

Comment: Ponlo entonces _como respuesta_ (en base a [answer]) y [acéptala](/help/accepted-answer) cuando transcurra el tiempo mínimo. Haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes convertir el input a número.
Es preferible usar `Number` en vez de `parseInt`. `parseInt("45a")` retorna el numero `45`, aún cuando `45a` no es un numero válido. `Number` si devuelve error con `45a`.

```
if(Number($(upslotsmas).val()) <= Number($(upslots).val())) { 
    alert("Es menor");
}
```